# SQL CREATE TABLE Error

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, authentication

The Answer was that I was using incorrect quotation marks instead of backticks. Stupid syntax hilighter tricked me.

I've been stuck on this one simple(ish) thing for the last 1/2 hour so I thought I might try to get a quick answer here.

What exactly is incorrect about my SQL syntax, assuming I'm using mysql 5.1

```
CREATE TABLE 'users' (
    'id' INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    'username' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    'password' VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    'salt' VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    'email' VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    'created_on' INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    'last_login' INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    'active' TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
) 
ENGINE InnoDB;
```

The error I get is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users';

CREATE TABLE 'users' (
    'id' INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,' at line 3


Elapsed Time:  0 hr, 0 min, 0 sec, 0 ms.
```

Also, does anyone have any good tutorials about how to use Zend_Auth for complete noobs?

Thanks.

Comment: why use back-ticks at all - pointless if you ask me

Comment: @f00: Some stubborn people out there insist on using certain keywords for identifiers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Table and column identifiers are quoted using backticks (or double quotes if you've configured them).

Additionally you have a comma at the end of your column list.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT( 8 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL,
    `salt` VARCHAR( 40 ) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL,
    `created_on` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `last_login` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    `active` TINYINT( 1 ) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE InnoDB
```

Comment: you are missing a ` after username :-)

Comment: No probs added some rep anyway

Comment: why not just id mediumint unsigned - what's the point of specifying a display width of 8 if you're not using zerofill ????

Comment: @f00, how do I know? It isn't problematic, so I didn't change it.

Answer (score 2):

You are using single quotes instead of backticks for your table and field names, which is wrong. There should also be an equals sign between `ENGINE` and `InnoDB`.

Here's the fixed SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    `salt` VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `created_on` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `last_login` INT(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
    `active` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```